# How does <transition-group> work with Vue.components?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component

Suppose I want to use the components to make a list that would disappear if I click on it, and use the `transition-group` to do the animation part.

The following code can perform well:

HTML:

```
<transition-group name="testanim">
  <p key="1" v-if='open1' @click='open1 = false'>Can You See Me?</p>
  <p key="2" v-if='open2' @click='open2 = false'>Can You See Me?</p>
</transition-group>
```

CSS:

```
.testanim-enter-active, .testanim-leave-active {
  transition: all .5s;
}
.testanim-enter, .testanim-leave-to {
  transform: translateX(1rem);
  opacity: 0;
}
.testanim-leave-active {
  position: absolute;
}
.testanim-move {
  transition: all .5s;
}
```

`open1` and `open2` are defined in `data` in Vue.js.

However, the following code would not perform the animation at all.

HTML:

```
<transition-group name="testanim">
  <test-sth key="1"></test-sth>
  <test-sth key="2"></test-sth>
</transition-group>
```

CSS: the same with above

JavaScript:

```
Vue.component ("test-sth", {
  template: "<p v-if='open' @click='open = !open'>Can You See Me?</p>",
  data: function () {
    return {
      open: true,
    }
  }
})
```

So the problem is that how I can animate the components inside the `transition-group`. I've searched for a few hours but did not find some question or documents related to it.

Update:

The key problem is that the animation in the former example that **the second sentence move upwards smoothly when the first sentense disappear** do not show in the latter one. Although I may put the `transition` inside the `template`, That do not solve the problem.
Should I write the whole `transition-group`inside the `template`, or something else...?

Answer (score 6):

When using Vue transitions, for internal reasons, the transition/transition-group components *must* be in the same template as the state that's being toggled.

Also, Vue components require that there always be a single root element for a component. A `v-if` breaks this rule because it gives the possibility of the element not being there, if the `v-if` happens to be false.

To solve your issue, move the transitioning to the `test-sth` component. Since it manages its own toggling, it should manage its own transitioning as well.

```
Vue.component("test-sth", {
  template: `
    <transition name='testanim'>
      <p v-if='open' @click='open = !open'>Can You See Me?</p>
    </transition>
  `,
  data: () => ({
    open: true,
  }),
})

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  template: `
    <div>
      <test-sth></test-sth>
      <test-sth></test-sth>
    </div>
  `,
})
```

[See this fiddle for a working example.](https://jsfiddle.net/Kingdaro/gkbLspf2/)

Comment: Sorry for the unclear problem description, but the actual problem is the animation effect of `v-move` part... I would update the question soon.